# How to call a view through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two views lets say

```
<?php if($_GET['view']=="happy"){?>
<div><p>I am Happy</p></div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($_GET['view']=="sad"){?>
<div><p>I am Sad</p></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now I have two `a` tags to call like

`<a href="mypage.php?view=happy">Happy view</a>`

`<a href="mypage.php?view=sad">Sad view</a>`

Is there a way to call these views through jquery or ajax? I don't want page to be reloaded. I know about `MVC` but I want to know if these views can be called through ajax or jquery

Comment: you have this tagged with ajax but I am not seeing ajax calls in your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to build a simplistic "single page" app where your views are updated without reloading the entire page.

The way to accomplish this is to have a container element (i.e. a ) where you can place a snippet of HTML you load from the server via ajax as a response to a user action.

You can add elements to a page, and attach a onClick event listener to them, so that when a user clicks on them, it makes an ajax call to the server and places the response inside the div.

I can provide code later to help better explain if you'd like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please provide an ajax code how to call a view! I know how to send data to a different script but data not something like this! Thanks if you provide a code :)

Comment: Thank you a lot for helping me!